# How to fix routers.get and app.use not working in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I used express-generator to create a new express Project and wanted to add a subrouting system like the following "localhost/" would take me to the index and "localhost/projects" would send "projects page" and "localhost/projects/randomCircles" would send "circles".

Node versión:v10.15.1

Express versión:4.16.0

[My Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VID.png)

Also tried to make randomCircles direct route and it worked but i don't get what's the difference

```
**app.js**:
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var projectsRouter = require('./routes/projects');
var circlesRouter = require('./routes/randomCircles');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/projects', projectsRouter);
app.use('/randomCircles', circlesRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;





**index.js**:
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'ProjectManager',menu: ['About Me','Projects','Contact Me']});
});
module.exports = router;

**project.js**:
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET projects list. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('projects page');
});
router.get('/randomCircles', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('circles');
});
module.exports = router;

**randomCircle.js*:

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET project randomCircles. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('randomCircles', {title: 'randomCircles'});
});
module.exports = router;
```

Routes that work:

- localhost/
- localhost/randomCircles

Routes that don't work:
 - localhost/projects
 - localhost/projects/randomCircles

I should be able to access "localhost/projects" but i get this error:

Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\app.js:27:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\josea\Documents\MEGAsync\coding\projectManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

*There was a typo in the routing system, edited the code of the post and now it works just fine <3*

Comment: What error are you getting? Are any of the routes working? Can you post your entire app.js file?

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: Thanks,edited the post to include all that information :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You also need to use `app.listen`

- While configuring your *routers* is necessary to have a functional *Express* app, you also need at some point to **[listen](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)** for incoming requests. Somewhere in your ***main*** server starting point, do this
- To import and integrate a router you defined in another file, first import it. Then add it using `app.use(myOtherRouter)`

---

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// Import your other router(s)
const someRouter = require('./myOtherRouter');

app.use(someRouter);

// Listen for incoming requests
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: I have already the listen method in a separate file, in fact some of the routes work the problem is why that one in particular doesn't do the job.P.S:thanks for the reply :P